# Hartshorne Exercise 1.1.1(c)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm looking for a solution to Hartshorne Exercise 1.1.1(c), that uses no, or as little as possible, coordinates transformations, and using only material from section 1 of Hartshorne.

> The question is to show that if $f\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is irreducible quadratic, then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ or $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$.

Here is the outline I have in mind:

If $\mathbb{C}\subsetneq A(W)^\times$, then let $u\in A(W)^\times\setminus \mathbb{C}$ be such that it has no root in $A(W)$ (i.e. there is no element $v$ s.t. $u=v^k$ for some $k>1$). Take the map $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]\to A(W),x\mapsto u$. This map is an isomorphism, the problem is how to prove it.

It is injective since the kernel is prime, and thus if nonzero corresponds to a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$, contradicting the assumption that $u\not\in\mathbb{C}$.

I'm having trouble showing that this map must be surjective without some annoying explicit computations. I think we could start by noting that $\mathrm{Frac}(A(W))$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathrm{Frac}(\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}])$. Then we assume that the degree of the extension is greater then $1$. Then this means that $u$ (any representative in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$) is at least quadratic. But $V(u)\cap W=\emptyset$, since $u$ is a unit in $A(W)$. Now I do not really how to proceed without resorting to doing some explicit computation anyway. So does someone know how to finish this in an elegant way?

In case $\mathbb{C}= A(W)^\times$ we would want to take an irreducible nonunit $u$, and construct the map $\mathbb{C}[x]\to u$. Again it is easy to see that this map is injective. In this case the map is surjective, since it having degree higher than $1$ contradicts the irreducibility of $u$.

Comment: What actually is exercise 1.1.1(c)? (And are 1.1.1(a) and 1.1.1(b) relevant to it?)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Added it in the edit.

Comment: Sorry but how do you find some $u$ such that $Frac(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)) = \mathbb{C}(x)[y]/(y^2+b(x)y+c(x))= \mathbb{C}(x,\sqrt{b(x)^2-4c(x)})= \mathbb{C}(u)$ ?

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but have you tried to reduce to the cases in parts (a) and (b)? By changing coordinates, I think you should be able to transform the conic into either a parabola (part (a)), or a hyperbola (part (b)).